# How does the compiler resolve infinite reference loops?

Tags: c++

```
// edited by Neil Butterworth to conserve vertical space
#include <stdio.h>

struct A;
struct B;

A& GetAInstance();
B& GetBInstance();

struct A {  
    A() {
        printf( "A\n" );
    }
    ~A() {
        printf( "~A\n" );
        B& b = GetBInstance();
    }
};

struct B {
    B() {
        printf( "B\n" );
    }

    ~B() {
        printf( "~B\n" );
        A& a = GetAInstance();
    }
}; 

A& GetAInstance() {
    static A a;
    return a;
}

B& GetBInstance() {
    static B b;
    return b;
}

int main( ) {
    A a;
}
```

Consider the above scenario. I would expect this to result in an infinite reference loop resulting in the program being unable to exit from static de-initialization, but the program ran just fine with the following printout:

```
  A
  ~A
  B
  ~B
  A
  ~A
```

Which was unexpected.

How does a compiler deal with this situation? What algorithms does it use to resolve the infinite recursion? Or have I misunderstood something fundamental? Is this, somewhere in the standard, defined as undefined?

Comment: Compiled with: g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21) on Linux <hostname> 2.6.18-5-amd64 #1 SMP <date> x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler effectively stores a `bool` with each `static` to remember whether it has been initialised.

This is the order:

Inside main:

- Construct `A`
- Destruct `A`
- - Construct `static B`

Clean-up of statics:

- Destruct `static B`
- - Construct `static A`
  - Destruct `static A`

3.6.3/1 in the Standard specifies it should work this way, even when a `static` is constructed during clean-up as in this case.

Comment: There are two instances of A, the static one and the one in main.

Comment: It's the static from GetAInstance()

Comment: Important Note: Is that the reference of B returned when destroying the static A is now a reference to an invalid or destroyed instance.

Comment: @Martin Actually it's a reference to an object that is being destroyed. Its lifetime has ended, so there are restrictions on what you can do with it, but there's no undefined behaviour.

Comment: @James: Never said there was (in the above code). There would be undefined behavior __if__ the destructor of A tried to use the reference of the static B to do anything (Which was the point I was trying to make above).

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is probably caused because you are using static instances. The compiler surely takes care of the status of static variables to avoid performing multiple initialization / deinitializations.