# Static function returning a static instance of the class - shouldn't the instance be the same?

Tags: c++, static-methods

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  static Test& get() {
    static Test testSing;
    return testSing;
  }
};

int main() {
  Test a = Test::get();
  Test b = Test::get();

  cout << &a << endl;
  cout << &b << endl;
}
```

I thought that `a` and `b` should have the same address, since I thought [they should be constructed only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567529/what-makes-a-static-variable-initialize-only-once). However, I get different memmory addresses in this test.

Is there something trivial that I am missing? Shouldn't they have the same address?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the copy constructor, so you have 2 different objects, references are missing.

You probably want

```
Test& a = Test::get();
Test& b = Test::get();
```

Comment: God, I don't know I missed something that obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`a` and `b` are assigned from the return value of `Test::get`, that mean they are copied, so they are independent variables. You may declare them as reference type, so change the code to:

```
Test &a = Test::get();
Test &b = Test::get();
```

You'll get what you want.

Answer (score 4):

> *"I thought that a and b should have the same address"*

As mentioned in the other answers, you're referring to copies of `Test`, and their addresses are different of course.

To make it a singleton class (as it seems to be intended) you explicitly prohibit using the default and copy constructors, and copy assignment operators:

```
class Test {
public:
  static Test& get() {
    static Test testSing;
    return testSing;
  }
private:
    // Forbid the following operations being used from public scope
    Test() {}
    Test(const Test&);
    Test& operator=(const Test&);
};
```

This way you'll get concise compilation errors in first place, besides unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yes, that was what I intended. I lack experience on this subject, though. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: use `=delete` since C++11.