# Is it a fixed order that all global variables are initialized prior to main()?

Tags: c++, global-variables

(Beginner Question:)
I initialized some global variables via user defined functions, and compared their execution sequence with main(). Result shows that these global variables' initialization come first.

I am not sure whether there is any execution sequence outside main function. May I confirm this is always the case (that global declarative region comes before `main()`)?

It is confusing to see that `c` being declared after `main()` but executed earlier.

Below is the code I used:

```
int foo(string);

int a = foo("a");       /* global var init */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  cout << "main() is now executed" << endl;
  return 0;
}

int b = foo("b");       /* global var init */

int foo(string s){
  cout << "foo() is now executed for : " << s << endl;
  return 42;
}

int c = foo("c");       /* global var init */
```

Result:

```
foo() is now executed for : a
foo() is now executed for : b
foo() is now executed for : c
main() is now executed
```

**Answer:**

No it is not fixed order. 
See n3797, 3.6.2/5:
**It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static or thread storage duration is done before the first statement of the initial function of the thread.**

Comment: Within the same translation unit, yes. Otheriwse, no.

Comment: Check this link: [When are static and global variables initialized?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783210/when-are-static-and-global-variables-initialized

Comment: Yes, the before main initialization of elements with static storage duration is guaranteed by the standard, but not the order of such initialization. Be careful with that, is known as the *static initialization fiasco*