# Difference between static variable in free function and static member function

Tags: c++, static-methods, linkage

I have such code:

```
struct Storage
{
    static int GetData()
    {
            static int global_value;
            return global_value++;
    }
};
int free_func()
{
    static int local_value;
    return local_value++;
}

int storage_test_func()
{
    return Storage::GetData();
}
```

Compiling it on OSX:

```
$ clang++ 1.cpp -shared
```

And running nm:

```
$ nm | c++filt
```

I am getting strange results:

```
0000000000000f50 T storage_test_func()
0000000000000f30 T free_func()
0000000000000f60 unsigned short Storage::GetData()
0000000000001024 bool free_func()::local_value
0000000000001020 D Storage::GetData()::global_value
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Two symbols (`local_value` and `global_value`) have different linkage! One visible difference is that `global_value` is defined in static member function and `local_value` is defined in free function.

Can somebody explain why it happens?

**UPD:**

After comments reading it looks like I should clarify things. 
Maybe using of `c++filt` was a bad idea. Without it it shows:

```
$ nm

0000000000000f50 T __Z17storage_test_funcv
0000000000000f30 T __Z9free_funcv
0000000000000f60 t __ZN7Storage7GetDataEv
0000000000001024 b __ZZ9free_funcvE11local_value
0000000000001020 D __ZZN7Storage7GetDataEvE5value
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

So yes. `__ZZ9free_funcvE11local_value` goes to BSS and `__ZZN7Storage7GetDataEvE5value` goes to data section.

`man nm` says that:

> If the symbol is local (non-external), the symbol's type is instead represented by the corresponding lowercase letter.

And that what I see. `__ZZ9free_funcvE11local_value` is marked with lowercase `b` and `__ZZN7Storage7GetDataEvE5value` is marked with capital `D`.

And this is the main part of the question. Why it happens like that?

**UPD2** 
One more way:

```
$ clang++ -c -emit-llvm  1.cpp
$ llvm-dis 1.bc
```

shows how these variables are represented internally:

```
@_ZZ9free_funcvE11local_value = internal global i32 0, align 4
@_ZZN7Storage7GetDataEvE5value = global i32 0, align 4
```

**UPD3**

Also there were some concerns about different sections symbols belong to. Putting `__ZZ9free_funcvE11local_value` to the text section does not change its visibility:

```
struct Storage
{
    static int GetData()
    {
            static int value;
            return value++;
    }
};


int free_func()
{
    static int local_value = 123;
    return local_value++;
}

int storage_test_func()
{
    return Storage::GetData();
}
```

Compiling:

```
$ clang++ 1.cpp -shared
```

Checking:

```
$ nm
```

Gives:

```
0000000000000f50 T __Z17storage_test_funcv
0000000000000f30 T __Z9free_funcv
0000000000000f60 t __ZN7Storage7GetDataEv
0000000000001020 d __ZZ9free_funcvE11local_value
0000000000001024 D __ZZN7Storage7GetDataEvE5value
```

Now both symbols are in data section but **still** one of those is **local** and another is **global**.
And the question is **why** it happens? Can somebody the logic on such compiler's decision?

Comment: The keyword `static` can have different meanings. Did you read [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html) or [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static)?

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in a local static variable in static member function, and a local static variable in a free function.

> Two symbols (local_value and global_value) have different linkage!

In standard nomenclature and from point of view of the standard, both of the variables have *no* linkage.

The relevant difference between the functions is not that one is a static member function and the other is not. The relevant difference is that the former is an inline function, but the latter is not.

Non-inline functions can only be defined in one translation unit, and therefore their local static variables do not need to be accessible from other translation units.

Inline functions on the other hand must be defined in every translation unit that use them. And, since the local static must refer to the same object globally, that object must be visible to multiple translation units.

Comment: Even if symbols are in different sections they still have different visibility. And this is the point of this question.

Comment: @Andigor oh, I get it now. I updated my answer to concentrate on that, rather than the initialization. This boils down to difference between inline and non-inline functions. Being a static member is just a distraction.

Comment: Should __attribute__((always_inline)) help to make local_value visible?

Comment: @Andigor maybe. I would imagine `inline` were enough. Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah! It helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The values will be linked in different storage sections.

> 000000000001020 D Storage::GetData()::global_value

The `D`shows that your variable will be linked to a section which will be initialized. From the `nm` man page:

```
       "D"
       "d" The symbol is in the initialized data section.
```

The `local_value` will not be initialized via the c-startup code.

After linking I got:

> 0804a0d0 b free_func()::local_value
>
> 0804a0d8 u Storage::GetData()::global_value

Also from `nm` man page:

```
       "B"
       "b" The symbol is in the uninitialized data section (known as BSS).

       "U" The symbol is undefined.

       "u" The symbol is a unique global symbol.  This is a GNU extension to the standard set of ELF symbol bindings.  For such a symbol the
           dynamic linker will make sure that in the entire process there is just one symbol with this name and type in use.
```

The reason is simply that the values will initialized via the standard startup initialization ( data section ) or not ( bss section ). The names for the section are not generally specified but used in common implementations.

You can find a lot Q&A to "When and where will which var initialized or not".
e.g.:
[When are static and global variables initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783210/when-are-static-and-global-variables-initialized)

Clarification: ( I hope )

That a variable is not initialized via startup code did not mean that is not initialized. A static variable inside a method/function is typically initialized in the first access of the containing code block. If you want to know how your compiler do this job, have a look in the assembly output.

For gcc you will find some `__cxa_` labels around the value initialization which protects your vars from multiple init.

Comment: shouldn't  `global_value` and `local_value` (poorly chosen name btw) both  be zero-initialized?

Comment: @bolov: I add some explanation

Comment: This question is not about initialisation. It is about visibility (or linkage).

Comment: @Andigor: The answer describes the reason for the different "linkage". :-) A variable which is stored in the data section will be initialized via the data init loop. And in bss section it will  not. And the question was about the "why".