# When is a `static const std::map` initialized, when not a member of class?

Tags: c++, static, initialization

A minimal example follows:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>

static const std::map<std::string,int> myMap= {
 {"a",1},{"b",2},{"c",3},{"d",4}
}

static const std::map<std::string,int> secondMap(myMap); /*(1)*/

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

When is the above map initialized?

My best guess is that it should be initialized before the call of `main`, but I couldn't find relevant text in the standard.

Can `myMap` be used by any other static variables without invoking undefined behavior?  point `/*(1)*/` demonstrates a possible usage.

Does the behavior change when the map is in a header file, instead of a translation unit?

I understand that there are different initialization phases for static variables in a C++ program, but the linked question does not answer which category the variable in the example belongs to.

My guess is that because it is constant, it would be static initialization, but honestly I'm not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783210/when-are-static-and-global-variables-initialized should help

Comment: In this program, potentially never. Nothing odr-uses it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables

Comment: I Update the question to reflect the suggestions.

Comment: `myMap` won't be zero-initialized, you provide explicit initializer to it. It will be initiliazed with what you gave, at some point before `main()` is called.

Comment: About the headers, compiler never "sees" them, `#include` is fancy word for copy paste. Of course including something twice then equals potentially defining something twice -> ODR violation.

Comment: The second paragraph of the accepted answer to the proposed duplicate should answer your main question, as long as you realize that the constructor of your map needs to be called. For your secondary questions, a key phrase for you to look up is "[tag:static-order-fiasco]" -- or you could just trust the last word of that and guess... ;)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof this link states that inside the same translation uinit static initialization is from top to bottom; Trouble would start in different compilation units.

Comment: @DávidTóth *"Trouble would start in different compilation units"* -- right. And you can rely on that if you want. As long as no one will ever decide your source file warrants being split into two.... ;)

Comment: I would definitely not want to :D